# Salesforce1 Publisher Actions canvas sdk download

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, canvas, publisher

Where can i download the javscript source to work with the Salesforce1 publisher events?

src='/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/publisher.js

Comment: [https://login.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/publisher.js](https://login.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/publisher.js)

Comment: Why not post this comment as an answer? Otherwise the question will remain open even though the information given is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://login.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/publisher.js

Thanks a lot for your commitment;)

Answer (score 1):

FULL VERSION
After you log in to your Salesforce org, go to:

http://YOURPOD.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js

MINI VERSION
If you're looking for the minimized version, go to:

http://YOURPOD.salesforce.com/canvas/sdk/js/publisher-min.js

where YOURPOD is the pod your org lives on, such as NA9.